# HHVM issue on ISPconfig MediaWiki installation

Tags: mediawiki, hhvm, ispconfig

I am about to setup Mediawiki on my VM (Debian Jessie, ISPconfig 3.1) and I get an error 500 when accessing the website. Here is my apache2 error.log:

```
[fastcgi:error] [pid 8066] (2)No such file or directory: [client 
51.15.70.216:56974] FastCGI: failed to connect to server 
"/var/www/clients/client1/web10/cgi-bin/hhvm-fcgi-[IP-address]-    
mydomain.com": connect() failed
[fastcgi:error] [pid 8066] [client 51.15.70.216:56974] FastCGI: 
incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server 
"/var/www/clients/client1/web10/cgi-bin/hhvm-fcgi-[IP-address]-80-
mydomain.com"
```

all rights are set OK for the webfolders, can anybody tell me please what I can do to get my configuration working?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is the hhvm deamon runing? It doesnt look so.

Comment: I think yes:

service --status-all | grep hhvm
` [ - ]  hhvm_web10`
also tried to restart hhvm:
`service hhvm_web10 restart`
same result:
[fastcgi:error] [pid 8064] (2)No such file or directory: [client 93.227.174.245:49726] FastCGI: failed to connect to server "/var/www/clients/client1/web10/cgi-bin/hhvm-fcgi-[IP-address]-mydomain.com": connect() failed
[Thu Apr 27 12:10:01.021054 2017] [fastcgi:error] [pid 8064] [client 93.227.174.245:49726] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/var/www/clients/client1/web10/cgi-bin/hhvm-fcgi-[IP-address]-mydomain.com"`

Answer (score 0):

I decided to install my Mediawiki without using HHVM for the first time. As long as the integration of HHVM in ISPC is not technically mature, it makes no sense to me.
Thanks for your help.